# sql / sqlplus - How to view schema

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I was just wondering - is there a command to view the schema for the database I have created?

- Using SqlPlus

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `DESCRIBE`. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm

Comment: `DESCRIBE` is definitely the way to go on a text terminal which SQL*Plus is. @TJR, please make your comment into answer so that the poster could accept it :)

Comment: `Describe` describes an object not the schema. I suspect that the OP is after the entire model as well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "view the schema"? Do you want to see the *current schema*?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this, and the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DESCRIBE` would be a good option.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has many views which store what is called the "Data Dictionary". Nearly all database objects are stored here and can be queried with regular SQL.

[Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/pls/tahiti/tahiti.catalog_views) has a good list of the data dictionary views.

For starters, take a look at the USER_ALL_TABLES view or DBA_ALL_TABLES view.

Comment: I actually think this is a valid question. What I believe he's looking for is a complete list of tables belonging to a particular database user; put another way, all relations that make up the entire DB schema, not just the columns and tuples (sometimes referred to as a schema) for one relation (aka table).

Comment: After connecting to the DB user at the command prompt, run "select * from cat;" and you'll get the output you want which is similar to what you'd see in SQL developer when you expand the "Tables" tree for a DB user.